# Predefined variable in include:rules condition matching in GitLab CI is not working

Tags: gitlab, include, gitlab-ci, rules

When I try to include files depending on branch the condition is always ignored.

Following [Use rules with include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-variables-with-include) by GitLab my include section is as below where I am trying to add `.gitlab-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-default-vars.yml` or `.gitlab-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-prod-vars.yml` file depending on branch.

```yaml
include:
  - local: /workflows/.gitlab-web-app-react-workflow.yml
  - local: /trigger-jobs/.gitlab-trigger-job-templates.yml
  - local: /rules/.gitlab-integration-rules.yml
  - local: /templates/.gitlab-notification.yml
  - local: /vars/deployment-environments/.gitlab-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-default-vars.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /(?!dev\/production$).*$/
  - local: /vars/deployment-environments/.gitlab-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-prod-vars.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /dev\/production$/
```

Also tried with different condition as `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` returns full ref path when used in `include:rules` such as

```yaml
- local: /vars/deployment-environments/.gitlab-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-default-vars.yml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /refs\/heads\/(?!dev\/production$).*$/
- local: /vars/deployment-environments/.gitlab-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-prod-vars.yml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /refs\/heads\/dev\/production$/
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using CI_COMMIT_BRANCH instead? I suggest adding a couple of lines in your script to check whether the pre-defined variable matches your regex, or at least echo the variable then run it through a checker. For example: /(?!dev\/production$).*$/ should match either dev or production or both, but dev\/production$ does not.

Comment: Hey @Arty-chan first of all thanks for taking time and commenting on the query. So now coming to the doubts you have

- Why not use CI_COMMIT_BRANCH instead? 
well, Gitlab says we can use very few selective variables with `include` keyword among which from 14.2 onwards they recommend using CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.
- The regular expression
`/(?!dev\/production$).*$/` This expression means/matches the strings without  `dev/production` substring. Hence if there is a string with `dev/production` substring  `if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /(?!dev\/production$).*$/` this rule returns false.

Comment: Without putting into a test project, it looks right, so I would definitely add some debug lines to see what's up.

Comment: Hmm I agree. This is although from the actual project. But I am wondering how I put the debug lines for the `includes`. Can you share some reference on that?